# Cannot load the GraphML file I just saved

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I'm using Gremlin Server.

I save the contents of the database in an XML file (GraphML) with this line:

```
g.io(path).write().iterate()
```

To load the file I use this line:

```
g.io(path).read().iterate();
```

And then I get this error:

```
connection.js:282
        new ResponseError(util.format('Server error: %s (%d)', response.status.message, response.status.code), response.status));
        ^
ResponseError: Server error: For input string: "-2555865115" (500)
```

This error is coming from gremlin server.

If I search for this value in the XML file (-2555865115) and I remove the last character (-255586511) then the problem is solved.

Why this happens? How can I fix this issue? The database is always saving a file that I have to fix manually.

If I have to change something in the configuration files of Gremlin Server, can you please tell me which file to modify and how? because I never did that before.

I'm using Gremlin server in my local computer just for testing, without any changes.

**EDIT:**

I changed conf/tinkergraph-empty.properties to this:

```
gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager=ANY
gremlin.tinkergraph.edgeIdManager=ANY
gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexPropertyIdManager=ANY
```

I restarted, but I get the same error when loading the XML file.

Comment: what is this `-2555865115` in your XML file? is it a property value of some sort? a vertex or edge id? i assume it should have the "5" that you are removing? is it that same value every time that causes a problem? or do other ones cause problems? can you recreate this in Gremlin Console or does it only happen with gremlin-javascript? Is there a more detailed server log error with stacktrace that could help resolve the issue? ideally, a Gremlin Console session output with a small sample xml file that demonstrates the problem would be the easiest way to sort this out .

Comment: Can you tell me how to save the database contents in an xml file and then load them using the gremlin console? what is the command and where the file will be located. My knowledge of gremlin console is limited and researching this is time consuming I don't have the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that removing the last integer from your numerical value solved the problem, I'd speculate you're hitting a limit; specifically, the lowest value an integer can have.

[In Java, that value is -2147483647](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE), and that happens to be the language that the [default implementation of Gremlin Server](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/tree/master/gremlin-server/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/server) is written in. As such, it's likely that the deserialization process is failing while trying to interpret that value as an integer. Since the value is below the minimum value of an integer, and since the error message talks about it being an input string, `Integer.parseInt("-2555865115")` is probably the call that's failing behind the scenes.

If Gremlin is both serializing and de-serializing the data, it might be a bug in that implementation, and you might want to [file an issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TINKERPOP/issues/TINKERPOP-2583?filter=allopenissues). In the mean time, consider implementing and registering a [custom serializer](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/dev/provider/#io-implementations) to give yourself more control over how the IO process works.