# GraphML saved from gremlin-server is corrupted with duplicated ids

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

When I call this to save my data as GraphML:

```
g.io(path).write().iterate()
```

The resulting XML file contains some vertices with duplicated ids, for example, this line is present 2 times in the xml for 2 different nodes:

```
<node id="17371">
```

This is gremlin-server creating data corruption and is causing problems for me. What can I do to fix this? is there a way to implement my own logic to assign the ids in the XML? maybe a setting I have to change in gremlin-server?

Comment: Is it possible you have the ID manager set to ANY and in one case you have an ID encoded as a number and in another a String? Java will view these as different IDs if so.

Comment: To try to fix [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458532/cannot-load-the-graphml-file-i-just-saved) typing problem on the xml I recently changed the .properties fles added ´gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager=ANY´ and ´gremlin.tinkergraph.edgeIdManager=ANY´ do you think that could be causing the problem? should I remove that?

Comment: If you know that 17371 is a duplicate - I would check to see if that appears in the graph twice. Once where the ID is a string and once where it is a number.